# Book []: Array Index Out of Bounds

Tags: java, arrays, object, indexing

I'm working on a method (`public Book[] getBooksWrittenBy(String authorLastName)`) that is supposed to return an array of book objects by an author's last name. My instructor e-mailed that it's coded right: check if all books are in constructor, and I have all 20 books in the constructor but when I try and run a test assignment class in my BlueJ project, it says `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`. When I test an object, it always shows 0 books by author. Can anyone see why that method would have an issue? It's the last method in the class below:

```
public class BookStore
{
     private String storeName; //e.g. "Jason's New Books"
     private Book[] inventory; //Array of Book objects

/**
 * creates the inventory Array of 100 book object
 * note that the list does not contain birth years nor death years for the authors, nor
 * years published for the books...just use 2013 for all of these dates
 * booklist[0] = new Book(new Author)(new Name("first", "last", "middle"), new Date(), new Date(),
 * new Date(), "ULYSSES")
 */

public BookStore()
{

    inventory = new Book[20];
    Book b1 = new Book(new Author(new Name("James", "Joyce", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
            new Date(), "ULYSSES");
    inventory[0] = b1;             

    inventory[1] = new Book(new Author(new Name("F.", "Fitzgerald", "Scott"), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "The Great Gatsby");
    inventory[2] = new Book(new Author(new Name("James", "Joyce", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "A Portrait Of The Artist As A Young Man");
    inventory[3] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Vladimir", "Nabokov", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "Lolita");
    inventory[4] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Aldous", "Huxley", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "Brave New World");
    inventory[5] = new Book(new Author(new Name("William", "Faulkner", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "The Sound and the Fury");
    inventory[6] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Joseph", "Heller", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "Catch-22");
    inventory[7] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Arthur", "Koestler", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "Darkness at Noon");
    inventory[8] = new Book(new Author(new Name("D.", "Lawrence", "H."), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "Sons and Lovers");
    inventory[9] = new Book(new Author(new Name("John", "Steinbeck", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "The Grapes of Wrath");
    inventory[10] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Malcolm", "Lowry", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "Under the Volcano");
    inventory[11] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Samuel", "Butler", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "The Way of all Flesh");
    inventory[12] = new Book(new Author(new Name("George", "Orwell", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "1984");
    inventory[13] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Robert", "Graves", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "I, Claudius");
    inventory[14] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Virginia", "Woolf", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "To the Lighthouse");
    inventory[15] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Theodore", "Dreiser", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "An American Tragedy");
    inventory[16] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Carson", "McCullers", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "The Heart is A Lonely Hunter");
    inventory[17] = new Book(new Author(new Name("Kurt", "Vonnegut", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "Slaughterhouse-Five");
    inventory[18] = new Book(new Author(new Name("George", "Orwell", " "), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "Animal Farm");
    inventory[19] = new Book(new Author(new Name("W.", "Maugham", "Somerset"), new Date(2013,1,1), new Date()),
        new Date(), "Of Human Bondage");              
}

/**
 * creates the inventory Array of 100 Book object
 * note that the list does not contain birth years nor death years for the authors, nor
 * years published for the books...just use 2013 for all of these dates
 * stores the storeName parameter in the storeName instance variable, but only if it
 * does not equal "Taylor's Used Books". If the parameter is "Taylor's Used Books", 
 * store the name as "Jason's Used Books" instead.
 * @param storeName   - the name of the book store
 */ 

public BookStore(String storeName) 
{
    if(storeName.equals("Taylor's Used Books"))
    {
        this.storeName = storeName; 
    }else if(storeName.equals("Taylor's Used Books"))
    {
        storeName = "Jason's Used Books"; 
    }else
    {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }


}

/**
 * accessor that gets store name
 * @return store name
 */ 

public String getStoreName()
{
    return storeName;
}

/**
 * mutator that sets store name
 * @param  -  store name
 */ 

public void setStoreName(String storeName)
{
    this.storeName = storeName;
} 

/**
 * returns the number of books written by an author whose last name is authorLastName
 * use a for loop
 * use .equalsIgnoreCase()
 */ 

public int howManyBooksDidThisAuthorWrite(String authorLastName)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++ )
    {
        if(inventory[i].getAuthorName().equalsIgnoreCase(authorLastName))
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

/**
 * returns the full name of the author who wrote the book by this title
 * returns null if there is no Book with this title, or if title is null of ""
 * use a for loop
 */

public String getAuthorFullName(String title)
{
    for(Book authorName : inventory)
        if (authorName.getTitle() != null && authorName.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title))
        {
            return authorName.getAuthor().getName().getFullName();
        }
    return null;
}

/**
 * returns null if there is no Book written by an author with authorLastName as their
 * last name
 * otherwise, returns an Array of Book objects(hint: declare and return a local Book[]
 * object containing all Book objects which were written by an author with this last name
 * (e.g. Orwell has two books in the list: 1984 and ANIMAL FARM)
 */

public Book[] getBooksWrittenBy(String authorLastName)
{
    int byAuthor = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++)
    {
        if(inventory[i].getTitle().equals(authorLastName))
        {
            byAuthor++;    
        }
    }

    Book[] matches = new Book[byAuthor];
    int indexNewArray = 0;
    for(int j=0; j < inventory.length; j++){
        if(inventory[j].getTitle().equals(authorLastName))
        {
            matches[indexNewArray] = inventory[j]; 
            indexNewArray++;
        }

    }
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: This is a whole lot of code, please give more info on exception thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the Book class it's impossible to give a perfect answer.

However from common sense, I suspect something may be wrong with your logic here:

`inventory[i].getTitle().equals(authorLastName)`

Can you see why this is a problem? (Hint: Think about what that line of code is saying in English, specifically what `getTitle()` means vs. what `authorLastName` means)

Comment: Never mind, I just solved it by changing the line to: inventory[i].getAuthor().getName().getLastName().equals(authorLastName)). It just cascaded down my whole project and fixed everything. I'll leave this post for anyone who wants to see it.